# primary key is not getting populated by entity framework 6 model first after saving entity to oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I can save an entity to Oracle 11g with EF 6.1.3. But the identity auto insert field is not getting updated in the object.

To my understanding, after calling SaveChanges, the object should be updated to include the new task_id. Why isn't it working?

```
var task = new TASK
{
    API_EXE_MAPPING_ID = mapping.MAPPING_ID,
    STATUS = "Creating",
    TASK_SYS_GUID = Guid.NewGuid()
};

_taskEntities.TASKS.Add(task);
_taskEntities.SaveChanges();
```

When I debug, the value of task.task_id is always 0 immediately following the line above.

The table definition is:

```
ALTER TABLE TC_QUEUE.TASKS
 DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;

DROP TABLE TC_QUEUE.TASKS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE TC_QUEUE.TASKS
(
  TASK_ID             NUMBER(10)                NOT NULL,
  TASK_SYS_GUID       RAW(16)                   NOT NULL,
  API_EXE_MAPPING_ID  NUMBER(38)                NOT NULL,
  STATUS              VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
  START_DATETIME      DATE,
  END_DATETIME        DATE
)
TABLESPACE TS_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TC_QUEUE.TASK_PK ON TC_QUEUE.TASKS
(TASK_ID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE TS_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TC_QUEUE.TASKS_AUTO_INSERT
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON TC_QUEUE.tasks
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT TC_QUEUE.tasks_seq.NEXTVAL
     INTO :new.task_id
     FROM DUAL;
END;
/


ALTER TABLE TC_QUEUE.TASKS ADD (
  CONSTRAINT TASK_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (TASK_ID)
  USING INDEX TC_QUEUE.TASK_PK
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

ALTER TABLE TC_QUEUE.TASKS ADD (
  CONSTRAINT TASK_MAPPINGS_FK 
  FOREIGN KEY (TASK_ID) 
  REFERENCES TC_QUEUE.API_EXE_MAPPINGS (MAPPING_ID)
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Here is the EDMX:

```
<EntityType Name="TASK">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="TASK_ID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="TASK_ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
  <Property Name="TASK_SYS_GUID" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="API_EXE_MAPPING_ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="STATUS" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
  <Property Name="START_DATETIME" Type="DateTime" />
  <Property Name="END_DATETIME" Type="DateTime" />
  <NavigationProperty Name="API_EXE_MAPPINGS" Relationship="Model.TASK_MAPPINGS_FK" FromRole="TASK" ToRole="API_EXE_MAPPING" />
</EntityType>
```

I've tried adding these annotations with no luck (the second as per the comments' suggestions):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int TASK_ID { get; set; }

[Key]
public int TASK_ID { get; set; }
```

I found similar posts on SO but with no luck.

Comment: What is the type of TASK_SYS_GUID? `Guid.NewGuid()` produces string like that 7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7 with is no convert to `number(10)` or ` int`

Comment: TASK_ID is the problem - You should be able to ignore TASK_SYS_GUID. TASK_ID is NUMBER(10) which maps to int. TASK_SYS_GUID is RAW(16) which makes to guid

Comment: Use [Key] annotation in TASK_ID

Comment: Still zero @EmdadulSawon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple bugs in the table definitions, which manifested them in this strange way. Resolving the bugs and updating the entities solved the issue.

First, the foreign key should have been mapping_id, not task_id

```
ALTER TABLE TC_QUEUE.TASKS ADD (
CONSTRAINT TASK_MAPPINGS_FK 
FOREIGN KEY (MAPPING_ID) 
REFERENCES TC_QUEUE.API_EXE_MAPPINGS (MAPPING_ID)
ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Second, the data types didn't match exactly on the mappings. One had a precision of 10, the other 38.

Very strange behavior...